# Tensorflow - Getting started issue (adding node result =0 )

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and installed it and made the getting started tutorial. There is always that warning: 
Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA Support and the results of the Addition is always 0 (see my code below).

What I already did:

1.Have you installed CuDNN, and if so, to what directory? (It should contain the file  cudnn64_5.dll .) --> Yes

2.Is that directory in your  %PATH%  environment variable? --> Yes

3.If not, and you add that directory to your  %PATH%  environment variable --> Yes

Any Ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
    Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

    H:\>python
    Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
    D64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cublas64_80.dll
locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll lo
cally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cufft64_80.dll l
ocally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll local
ly
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library curand64_80.dll
locally
>>> node1 = tf.constant(3.0, tf.float32)
>>> node2 = tf.constant(4.0)
>>> print(node1, node2)
Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=f
loat32)
>>> sess = tf.Session()
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core
\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro K1100M
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.7055
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 2.00GiB
Free memory: 1.54GiB
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core
\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core
\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core
\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (d
evice: 0, name: Quadro K1100M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core
\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:586] Could not identify NUMA node of /job:loca
lhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0, defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been bu
ilt with NUMA support.
>>> print(sess.run([node1, node2]))
[3.0, 4.0]
>>> node3 = tf.add(node1, node2)
>>> print("node3: ", node3)
node3:  Tensor("Add:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
>>> print("sess.run(node3): ",sess.run(node3))
sess.run(node3):  7.0
>>> a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
>>> b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
>>> adder_node = a + b
>>> print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b:4.5}))
0.0
>>> print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: [1,3], b: [2, 4]}))
[ 0.  0.]
```

Comment: It looks like it worked for you when you used `tf.add` with two constants. Does the problem persist if you use `tf.add` with the placeholders? Or if you use the `+` operator with the constants?

Comment: When I am using int32 placeholders instead of float 32, then the computation works fine

Comment: Problem stays when i use tf.add with placeholders

Comment: Could you include the output of nvidia-smi in your post?

Comment: I am unsure why you are receiving wrong outputs, but I will note the message about the "NUMA node" is almost certainly a red herring and unrelated to your real problem. I would suggest: update your NVIDIA driver, CUDA, CuDNN, and Tensorflow all to the latest versions, and add that information here. If the problem still persists, I would probably file an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if this is it, but it could be because of the [CUDA compute capability](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) of your NVIDIA Quadro K1100M GPU, which is 3.0. [The installation documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) says it should be enough, but [in this FAQ](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#does_tensorflow_make_use_of_all_the_devices_gpus_and_cpus_available_on_my_machine) says you need 3.5. Looking at [this source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc), it does look like [XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/) require 3.5; what I do not know is whether TensorFlow ignores XLA if your compute capability is below 3.5 (which would be nice) or instead tries to use it and fails with no error message (which would be awful).

If that happened to be indeed the problem (and assuming you want to avoid upgrading your hardware), you can probably still use TensorFlow in your GPU just by disabling XLA and adding support for CUDA 3.0 in a custom build, as explained (to some extent) [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources).

Comment: XLA is not related to the problem; it is not enabled by default (even if you turn it on at configure time). XLA is also not yet even built on Windows.

Comment: @PeterHawkins Thanks for that info. I assumed that it was included, since it is already mentioned [on the website](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/), but it does say it is experimental.